# Error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' running the msbuild on a tfs continuous integration process

Tags: c#, tfs, c#-5.0, c#-6.0, .net-framework-version

I have a project that the framework is targeting `.NET Framework 4.6.1`, as part of the continuous integration process on the tfs we created a Build Solution task to ensure that the code compiles correctly.
Now the TFS server has the latest version of the `.Net Famework 4.6.2`. On the register this is the value for the Release key of the framework

> On all other OS versions: 394806  => .NET Framework 4.6.2

But when the build runs it comes with this error:

```
Error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'
```

I don't want to replace the string interpolation with the `string.Format` to solve this issue, please provide another workaround to solve it.

Do I need to install something else on the TFS server?

Comment: What version of MSBuild is running on the server?

Comment: You need to update the `MSBuild` tool, not the `.NET` framework

Comment: @VMAtm how can I do that? I just downloaded https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 and that is the one that is failing

Comment: @Heinrich added an answer

Comment: this answer solved this issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180393/buildactivity-ignores-toolsversion

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem can be fixed installing a Nuget package
Microsoft.Net.Compilers. Below is the link of my highlighted answer: [Project builds fine with Visual Studio but fails from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826517/project-builds-fine-with-visual-studio-but-fails-from-the-command-line/42931980#42931980)

> That feature is a syntactic sugar for C#6, try to install the latest
>   version of the framework 4.6.2 
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53345
>
> Then go to your Project properties and change on the Application
>   option on Target framework to point to the latest. You don't need to
>   change your code to replace the string interpolation with
>   string.Format method to fix it. If you are still getting this error,
>   is because, the compiler that is running your build is not the latest
>   version of C#, try to add the Microsoft.Net.Compilers, from Nuget and
>   compile again, that should resolve the issue. If you want to avoid to
>   install this package, try to open your .csproj and take a look on the
>   ToolsVersion.that should be pointing to the version 12, then change it
>   to 14, but make sure you have installed the latest version of the
>   MSBuild from
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 or go
>   to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin, there you should have this
>   folder with the csc.exe compiler. If even then that doesn't resolve
>   the issue, then try to follow this steps
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx.

In my experience I solved this problem in 3 different ways:

1- just getting the package from Nuget

2- installing Microsoft Build Tools 2015 on the tfs server

3- The sledgehammer and last options but for me the best because you don't need to deal with the dependency on nuget, is installing the visual studio version on the tfs server where you run the process.

Hope this helps

Comment: Installing the dependency for this Nuget package fixed my problem. Is there any way to avoid installing the dependency if I have 100 projects?

Comment: Take a look on my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43072823/819153

Answer (score 14):

After installing the [MS Build tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) into `%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\14.0\bin` you need to [**override the MSBuild version for build server**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx) with new value (`14.0`).

You should read the MSDN article (or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364698/213550)), but **TL;DR** your options are:

- Override version by using the `/ToolsVersion` switch (or `/tv`, for short) when you build the project or solution from the command line:

  ```
  msbuild.exe someproj.proj /tv:14.0 /p:Configuration=Debug
  ```
- Override version by setting the `ToolsVersion` parameter on the `MSBuild` task:

  ```
  <MSBuild Projects="myProject.proj"  
      ToolsVersion="14.0"  
      Targets="go" />
  ```
- Override version by setting the [`$(Project.ToolsVersion)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796.aspx) property on a project within a solution. This lets you build a project in a solution with a `ToolsetVersion` that differs from that of the other projects:

  ```
  <Project ToolsVersion="14.0" ... </Project>
  ```

> The order of precedence, from highest to lowest, used to determine the `ToolsVersion` is:
>
> 1. The `ToolsVersion` attribute on the `MSBuild` task used to build the project, if any.
> 2. The `/toolsversion` (or `/tv`) switch that's used in the `msbuild.exe` command, if any.
> 3. If the environment variable `MSBUILDTREATALLTOOLSVERSIONSASCURRENT` is set, then use the current `ToolsVersion`.
> 4. If the environment variable `MSBUILDTREATHIGHERTOOLSVERSIONASCURRENT` is set and the `ToolsVersion` defined in the project file is greater than the current `ToolsVersion`, use the current `ToolsVersion`.
> 5. If the environment variable `MSBUILDLEGACYDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION` is set, or if `ToolsVersion` is not set, then the following steps are used:
>
>    - The `ToolsVersion` attribute of the [`Project`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcxfsh87.aspx) element of the project file. If this attribute doesn’t exist, it is assumed to be the current version.
>    - The default tools version in the `MSBuild.exe.config` file.
>    - The default tools version in the registry. For more information, see [Standard and Custom Toolset Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397428.aspx).
> 6. If the environment variable `MSBUILDLEGACYDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION` is not set, then the following steps are used:
>
>    - If the environment variable `MSBUILDDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION` is set to a `ToolsVersion` that exists, use it.
>    - If `DefaultOverrideToolsVersion` is set in `MSBuild.exe.config`, use it.
>    - If `DefaultOverrideToolsVersion` is set in the registry, use it.
>    - Otherwise, use the current `ToolsVersion`.

Comment: I tried all of this changes, even I change the values on the register to the change the default version to 14.0, also I changed the MSBuild.exe.config but everything was unsuccessful. My project has the correct ToolsVersion

Comment: @Heinrich you also need to make sure that you're running msbuild.exe from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\" (not from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\)

Comment: for me the path was `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"`

Answer (score 8):

There is a chance you are building with the wrong MSbuild.exe; do the compile in Visual Studio (where it works) and check the logs in Output. There should be something like:

```
1>Target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets"
```

Make sure you are using the MSBuild.exe in that Bin directory, in my case;

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSbuild.exe
```

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft.Net.Compilers didnt work, but installing [DotNetCompilerPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/) from Nuget did.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem because I used the wrong msbuild path. I was using `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe` which corresponds to old versions of Visual Studio and Frameworks, now I use Visual Studio 2019, so the correct path to build is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe` depending on the architecture you want to build.

Comment: If you have only the Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools installed without Visual Studio it will be at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe

Answer (score 3):

My solution was 2 part:

1) Using Visual Studio 2015, select your web project, click the *Project* menu, select "Enable C# 6"

2) I needed to add the following to the end of my production web.config, just before the configuration closing tag. Note that version numbers may change in the future, but the key is to look for similar text in your development web.config after enabling in step 1 and make sure it gets transferred to production.

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use msbuild version 15.

Comment: This one helped in my case. I was getting the above error from TeamCity. Changing the MSBuild version to 15 did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing that you have code with string interpolations and don't have the [proper build tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159).

Comment: Actually I have a higher version of that tool installed on the server

Comment: It would have helped to see the code where the error is happening.