# SSIS compiles in BIDS, fails in DTEXEC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, visual-studio-2017, bids

I have a SSIS package, it runs fine in visual studio with BIDS, where it is developed (except for running out of memory due to 32-bit limitation).
Now, when I re-build the package, copy the dtsx to another location and ask DTEXEC to run it, I will get bombarded with log messages of this kind:
"Description: CS1056 - Unexpected character '$', ScriptMain.cs, 660, 39".

From what I have been able to find, this relates to the fact that I use string interpolation as part of some of my script tasks (C#). The C# version is set to Visual Studio C# 2015 and all scripts compile fine in visual studio.

DTEXEC does tell me that it failed to compile scripts in the package, but how come it does so, when visual studio compiles and runs it just fine?

Besides the above mentioned error, I do also get:

1. "Description: CS1519 - Invalid token '.' in class, struct, or interface member declaration, PIMChannelStructureEntity.cs, 10, 42".
2. "Description: CS1002 - ; expected, PIMChannelStructureEntity.cs, 10, 30".
3. "Description: CS1520 - Method must have a return type, PIMChannelStructureEntity.cs, 10, 43".

For 1, 2 and 3 above I have inspected the individual scripts and there are NO compile errors or warnings.
I expect that 1, 2 and 3 are symptoms of something else being wrong, as the code compiles just fine in visual studio.

The package is being run like:
/FILE "E:\packageName.dtsx" /CONNECTION connName1;"Data Source=server;User ID=username;Password=password;Initial Catalog=catalog1;Persist Security Info=True;Max Pool Size=10000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30;Application Name=someLongAssAutogeneratedName;" /CONNECTION connName2;"Data Source=anotherServer;User ID=anotherUsername;Password=anotherPassword;Initial Catalog=catalog2;Persist Security Info=True;Application Name=anotherLongAssAutogeneratedName;"  /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING IEW   /CONSOLELOG NCSMT

The package does point to the correct SQL server version.

Any and all suggestions as to what could be wrong, are very much appreciated. I am at a loss.

EDIT:

1. The suggested duplicate I have already looked at, and it didn't get me any closer to a solution. This issue is in no way or shape related to TFS or build processes.
2. The package is being run against a 2016 SQL server.
3. 2nd line when executing: "Version 14.0.1000.169 for 64-bit"
4. When running the package through DTExecUI it is validated 100% and passes. It will run but hit the same 32-bit limitation as from inside Visual Studio. Perhaps this is an issue between 32 and 64 bit runtime?
5. After having replaced every occurrence of String Interpolation ($"") with the equivalent string.Format(...), the validation fails on every occurrence of ':', ';', '.' and so on, for what seems to be every line outside the Main method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' running the msbuild on a tfs continuous integration process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932577/error-cs1056-unexpected-character-running-the-msbuild-on-a-tfs-continuous-i)

Comment: When you run it with DTExec, what version of SQL Server is it running on?

Comment: @TabAlleman I run it on my own computer through DTExec, for testing purposes. But as I have updated the question with, it runs against a 2016 SQL server.

Comment: What is the second line from the output of dtexec? First is "Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility"

Comment: And to cover the basics, how did you copy the package to the server? If you run the package on your machine outside of the debugger and the 32 bit memory limitation (Ctrl-Shift-F5 maybe?) do you get the same error?

Comment: @billinkc For your first question see the third edit. To answer your second question, the package is currently being run on my own computer, for testing purposes (I don't have access to the server). I have just copied the .dtsx file to a location on my drive, form where I try to run it. Once deployed, the .dtsx file is handed over to our DBA, who will have it run via a job in SQL server.