# Visual Studio - Azure DevOps encoding mismatch

Tags: git, visual-studio, encoding, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

Following line builds locally in Visual Studio

```
Assert.IsNotNull(login.Prihlásenie);
```

But in Azure DevOps build pipeline I'm getting error

> Error CS1056: Unexpected character '¾'

I guess it is because of the different charset in my local Windows. Is is possible to force Visual Studio always save files with unicode encoding or whatever the build agent expects?

Comment: What version of VS/MSBuild are you using locally? And which agent image do you use in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your local VS/MSBuild has the same version as Azure DevOps agent image. Then check case [Error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' running the msbuild on a tfs continuous integration process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932577/error-cs1056-unexpected-character-running-the-msbuild-on-a-tfs-continuous-i), to see whether the solution installing a Nuget package Microsoft.Net.Compilers is working for you.

Last, you may save a file with encoding by following the documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2019

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?